# How to delete observations in a SAS Table Using the _n_ variable

Tags: sas

I am trying to delete rows in a SAS data set that does not have data in specific rows. Is it possible to do it by including the variable for the Obs column (i.e., the variable *n*)?

I used the following Data Step, but it did not seem to work (rows 809-868 do not have data, and I am trying to delete those rows):

```
data two; 
set one; 
if  _n_ >=809 or _n_<=868 then delete; 
run;
```

Any input regarding this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_n_ is an automatic variable that is set to the index of the implicit loop iteration at the top of the DATA step.  It can be used as a proxy for 'row number' but should not be relied for that.

You can visualize gaps created by deleting according by *n* by creating a saved variable.

```
data want;
  set have;
  myrownumber = _n_;
  if 809 <= _n_ <= 868 then delete;
run;
```

Looking at the output you will see a gap in the numbers shown for `myrownumber`.

A better approach is define the criteria for your condition *does not have data* and filter based on that.  For a 'does not' mindset there are functions such as `N(), NMISS(), CMISS()` that can count how many values are present or missing in a row.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean 'did not work'?
SAS does what you tell him to do.

The issue here is that you used the `or` operator instead of `and`.

```
data have;
do obs=1 to 1000;
    x = rand('integer', 1, 10);
    output;
end;
run;
```

```
data want;
set have;
if _n_ >= 809 and _n_ <= 868 then delete; 
run;
```

```
data want;
set have;
if 868 => _n_ >= 809 then delete; 
run;
```

```
NOTE: There were 1000 observations read from the data set WORK.HAVE.
NOTE: The data set WORK.WANT has 940 observations and 2 variables.
```

Comment: Indeed, the original `OR` is really the crux of the problem.